# how to restrict root access to folders on aix?

Tags: aix

I want to restrict access to certain folder on aix.

even root user should be restricted to access certain folders.
for e..g i have user - aixuser and root on aix 5.3 server
and i have a folder - myfolder.

i want only aixuser to have access to this folder and not root.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be done. The whole concept of the root user relies on unfettered access. You can quite easily protect your files from other regular users, using either the user/group/other paradigm or access control lists but, once someone has root powers, you cannot restrict them at all.

There's a good reason for this - if you lost access to your files somehow, how would you expect the administrators to recover them for you?

The way of dealing with your concerns is to either restrict the number of people with root access or somehow encrypt your files. But even *that* latter suggestion wouldn't stop a determined root user who can look inside your process address spaces or intercept your input stream to grab your passwords if need be.

The only workable security will be having your own box with only you having the root powers. Then you can treat a root user on a different box as just a regular user on yours.

Comment: RBAC can allow non-root users to do some tasks normally only allowed to root users but it does not (and should not) restrict the root user in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude root access to any file on any local file system.

Answer (score 0):

as paxdiablo is saying, root user privilege is the ultimate thing in AIX (infact any UNIX/Linux machine). In RBAC, setting the role permissions to aix (in the mkrole command) will give you permissions to do everything a root user can do but nothing more than the root user.

Having UID=0, GID=0 gives **root** all the access it needs on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe you can do it with the encrypted file system.  I have not done it.  Sorry for the vague reply.  But I believe EFS has two modes.  One is to trust root and the other is to not trust root.

From https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-efs/index.html

```
AIX® EFS encryption is at the file system level. Each file is protected with a unique file key, and protection is created against malicious root.
```

If you really think about it, encryption is the only choice you have.  Root can open up the hard disk and copy it over to another drive, then go monkey with the file system itself do what it pleases.  The only way to protect against root is via encryption.